# Overriding style of geoJSON in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am loading a data layer via calling a geoJSON file. I am drawing around 100+ polygons using the geoJSON file. I am setting the style via my js code, but the issue is that when the map loads the polygons it shows the strokes/fill colors with some default black shades for some milli seconds and then apply my color schemes correctly. Is there any way I can avoid this effect?

```
 zipLayer = new google.maps.Data({
        map: map1,
        style: {
            strokeColor: '#ff0000',
            strokeOpacity:.8,
            strokeWeight:1,
            fillColor: '#ff0000',
            fillOpacity:.1
        }
    });

    var url = 'url/to/polygons';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success:function(data) {
            zipLayer.addGeoJson(data);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `map.data.loadGeoJson` method?

Comment: I cannot use loadGeoJson as I need to post data to url.

Comment: You aren't doing that in the example in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map.data.loadGeoJson` method.

```
zipLayer = new google.maps.Data({
    map: map1,
    style: {
        strokeColor: '#ff0000',
        strokeOpacity:.8,
        strokeWeight:1,
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity:.1
    }
});

zipLayer.addGeoJson('url/to/polygons);
```

Comment: Yes! loadGeoJson rendered the layer in correct style, but how I will clear a particular layer in this case?

Comment: That is probably another question.  How were you clearing it before?  The same method should work.